# Android source project files generation fails

Tags: android, android-source, projects-and-solutions

I am having problem generating files for loading Android Source into Android Studio IDE. Running idegen.sh ends with **Error: Could not find or load main class Main**

Command I run is (sudo because the source is on an NTFS partition mounted by root) :

```
sudo make idegen && sudo development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh
```

Which gives this output:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=6.0.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.6.3-1-ARCH-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=MASTER
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
[1/2] choosing next stage
Choosing primary.ninja.in for next stage
[2/2] bootstrap out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja.in
[1/2] choosing next stage
Choosing main.ninja.in for next stage
[2/2] bootstrap out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja.in
ninja: no work to do.
Running kati to generate build-aosp_arm.ninja...
No need to regenerate ninja file
Starting build with ninja
ninja: Entering directory `.'
ninja: no work to do.
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

I have already build the entire source and it runs in emulator. But this error is very general and it got me stuck here.